# aspnet core web api and SPA (ReactJs) in Single Docker container

Tags: docker, containers, single-page-application, webapi

Is it okay to create single Docker Image for both SPA(ReactJs app) and Aspnet Core Web Api? OR both should be pushed in a separate container? What's the best practice to achieve this? any source of the information would be great

Comment: If the React application is compiled to static files, there's nothing wrong with serving it from your application container.  This is probably better practice than running a dev server in a separate container; there are also setups that serve static files from a separate Nginx container, and those are fine too.

Comment: Thanks @David, if I have to set up devops for both ReactJs and Aspnet Core webapi separately (of course with two separate containers) then is there any document or tutorial I need to follow?